# Is there a term for syntactically and semantically linked modifying phrases?

Tags: syntax, english, terminology

What I'm talking about is when a string of prepositional phrases take the object of the previous one as their antecedent, and where the entire string is linked back to the original antecedent, a noun or a verb or an adjective.

Linking back to an adjective:

> John was **happy** *about* his ***acceptance*** as a 
>   ***member*** of the varsity team.

Linking back to a verb:

> These tiny flowers **transform** *into* pulp-filled ***pods*** *about*
>   the **size** *of* rugby balls.

Linking back to a noun:

> I need a **book** *about* medical **conditions** *in* **children** *from* Zimbabwe.

The order of the phrases is fixed, it cannot change without breaking the sentence or producing a different meaning or nonsense. The chain functions as a single unit to modify the original antecedent.

This is very different from modifying phrases that form independent relations with a verb, noun or adjective. The order of these phrases can change without changing the meaning of the sentence (just an observation).

Linking back to a verb (independent adverbials):

> I teach at a university in the morning during the summer months every
>   other year.

Linking back to a noun (independent noun modifiers):

> Max observed the painting on the wall at the museum in the main hall.

Linking back to an adjective (independent adjective modifiers):

> He was distinguished in his field for his achievements with an award.

The order of the phrases is not fixed, it can change without changing the meaning of the sentence. Each phrase has an independent relation to original antecedent.

This seems like a very significant different in syntax and I haven't been able to find much that addresses this phenomena.

I apologize if my terminology is off - please feel free to offer corrections.

How is this feature of the language analyzed in linguistics?

Comment: *at* University, *ob-*serve the painting, *dis-*tinguished with an award. The last one is arkward because there's strong precedence for *ad-ward* as the head verb.

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at - can you be a tad more specific?

Comment: oh, I accidentally the markup. Anyhow, I can only return the question, because I'm not sure what you are trying to say with your markup, and why you omitted it in the other examples

Comment: In the sentence that are marked up I was drawing attention to he dependencies, and since there is none in the latter set, I omitted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an interesting question, and my answer is that you are noticing two different syntactic phenomena merging together. The differences are both structural (which phrases are *constituents*) and in the types of attachment between phrases (*adjuncts* vs. *complements*).

In your first three examples, the later prepositional phrases are not modifying the main clause, but rather the phrase they are immediately nested in. To give an example with things bracketed, each bracket is a phrase that can be used as its own noun phrase constituent.

> I need [a book about [medical conditions in [children from Zimbabwe]]].

"from Zimbabwe" is telling you where the children are, not where the book is, etc.

In the second set of examples, the phrases are not part of the clause they are next to, but rather refer back to the original phrase they are modifying. The bracketing I am using here is highlighting the main phrase and the prepositional phrases modifying it.

> Max observed [the painting [on the wall] [at the museum] [in the main hall]].

Notice that "at the museum" is telling you where the painting is, not where the wall is ("the wall at the museum" is not a constituent).

The other phenomenon is that there are two different types of modifying going on here. Some of those prepositional phrases are "adjuncts" to the phrases they are in, and some are "complements."

An adjunct is a modifier that does not change the core meaning of the phrase ("the painting on the wall" does not give you a different object than "the painting"). You can have multiple adjuncts modifying the same object, and tend to be reörderable (the second set of phrases all have at least 2 adjuncts).

A complement tends to change the core meaning of the phrase they are a part of ("the size" does not mean "the size of rugby balls"), and is sometimes even mandatory ("*I depend" is not a good sentence; it needs to be "I depend on something"). Complements tend to occur at most once for each head, and when you have both complements and adjuncts together, complements tend to be the closest to the head. That is, you can say "I saw pods the size of bananas in length," but not "*I saw pods the size in length of bananas."

Putting this all together, a lot of the prepositional phrases in the first examples are complements of their heads, and so cannot be interpreted as modifying the head of the phrase in the main clause, while the phrases in the second set of examples are adjuncts, and so can easily modify the head of the phrase in the main clause.

Comment: +1 If there were a test for the "complement/adjunct" distinction that didn't depend on measuring the displacement of "core meaning", I'd like this answer even better.

Comment: I fully agree with your assessment! I would find the answer even better, if you would directly refer to the question in the first paragraph, like: the terms you're looking for are complement vs. adjunct on the one hand, and constituency on the other one.

Comment: There are plenty of "complement/adjunct tests" that give much more solid answers. I was just going for explaining what they were and how they were different.

I also edited the post to introduce the concepts a bit sooner.

Comment: The problem I have as an ESL teacher is that all of this is blindingly beyond what most learners will tolerate in order to acquire English. I don't fully understand it myself, though I am trying to get my head around these difficult concepts and all their inherent relations to other concepts. I have a hard time seeing the usefulness of constituency when the tests for them seem to produce numerous and different sets of constituents. Adjunct and complement are more useful but still rather complex for most learners.

Comment: That said the difference in the way the sentence complelement phrases produce their meaning is distinct and helpful for students to see, and pretty easy for them to understand. Unfortunatey, the term *phrase* is rather opaque and what constitutes a phrase is a matter of the terms of analysis used. Which is why I only talk about sentence phrases (S|V|C) and word phrases (np, vp, pp, avp, ajp) with my students. I have developed a system to analyse sentences and I've tried to stay in bounds, linguistically speaking, but I fear it may only earn me scorn.

Comment: That's context that would have been great to know, because this is an answer that can be given with more or less focus towards certain parts of it, and the takeaways that would interest a theoretical linguist about "how do we talk about the subtle differences in these similar sentences" is very different than the takeaways that would interest an ESL teacher. I can try to write a new answer that might be more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: Thanks - I do appreciate your answer, I hope that was clear, and I wouldn't be a good teacher had I not entered the waters so to speak - what I've learned from my limited study of linguistics has been enormously helpful, while at the same time a bit confounding. I find so much of tradtional and even modern instructional grammars to be problematic that I've begun to organize my own approach. If you would care to answer my question with this new information in mind I would be quite grateful.

Comment: Yeah, I totally get that. Those structural analyses are actually all using just NPs and PPs, just in a very condensed format, instead of making it clear, so I was planning on making a more expanded version when I had time. Though, it might be a good idea if I knew a bit more of your method, to try to make sure I am understanding what you are looking for.

Comment: So, let me try again with "I need [*a book* about [*medical conditions* in [*children* from [Zimbabwe]]]]" each of the brackets represents a single noun phrase. A noun phrase can have a prepositional phrase modifying the head (the bit that determines the type of the phrase, such as the noun in a noun phrase), and PPs can have a noun inside them, which is the head of a NP nested within the PP. Unlike Max observed [the painting [on the wall] [at the museum] [in the main hall]], where the three nested PPs are all modifying the "painting" and not a noun within another PP.

Comment: As word phrases, pp are a bit suspect - because, while the other wrod phrases produce a discrete package of meaning (subject to modification, of course), the pp is inherently incomplete and dependent on its antecedent. Som if a word phrase can be defined as a discrete information package, pp don't actually quaify. Anyway, I would like to share my ideas with you but this is not the place - I've included contact information in my profile, so, if you're interested please do reach out. It's pretty well developed at this point, and I think you will, at least, find it interesting.

Comment: Anyway, the suggested terms, adjunct, complement and constituent do not answer my question. these are linked to different theories and produce different results and call the string of word phrases by the head - so 'a book about medical conditions in children from Zimbabwe' would be a noun phrase (I guess). It seems there is no specific term for these long 'nested' phrases that trace back to a head word. It would be nice for my students, to call them something, like 'trace' or 'head' phrases, or something.